# How to query request object in Facebook graph API explorer?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a request Id and I'd like to get the request Id object.

When I type the request id into the graph api explorer I get this: "Unsupported get request."

Any idea how to do this?

I'd like the request objects like at the end of this example: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/

Thanks!

*EDIT* My code:

First I enter this in my browser:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?
  app_id=APP_ID&
  message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

Then examining the response in Chrome I can see this under Query String Parameters:

```
request:600744979955487
to[0]:6025656
to[1]:630243457
to[2]:100002049936997
to[3]:100003709530244
```

These are the Ids of the friends I sent the request to and the request ID.

I use that data to construct this request in the Graph Api Explorer

```
/600744979955487_6025656
```

I also tried:

```
/600744979955487
```

Both return:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Comment: You haven't posted any code, What end point are you trying? https://graph.facebook.com/USERID/apprequests ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call with the `access_token`

> To get the full Request that includes the recipient user, you will need to append the recipient user ID:

`https://graph.facebook.com/<REQUEST_OBJECT_ID>_<USER_ID>?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN`

> or use the recipient User Access Token:

`https://graph.facebook.com/<REQUEST_OBJECT_ID>?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN`

-- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/requests/

Comment: @user2066743 Are you using the app access token or the user access token

Comment: Yeah, turns out I was using different access token